# Steam not opening - "tar: This does not look like a tar archive"

Tags: steam, budgie

I am new to Linux and I have Ubuntu 17.04 64-bit (Budgie).

I cannot open steam. It is updated to latest version. When I open it it pops up but after some time it disappears. When I try to run it from a terminal I get this output:

```
tar: This does not look like a tar archive
xz: (stdin): File format not recognized
tar: Child returned status 1
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
find: ‘/home/ghazi/.steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime’: No such file or directory
```

Comment: it's very strange that you get this output! What command are you using in the terminal exactly?

Comment: i just simply write steam because writing the name of app in terminal opens it

Comment: that was the right thing to do, however I am surprised that steam is calling `tar` to do something. Hopefully someone can explain it

Comment: @Zanna not that surprising. The Steam client downloads runtime updates directly from Steam servers. Presumably this tar archive is an update that got corrupted or partially downloaded.

Comment: so what do i need to do?

Comment: **OR** you can just delete the 'home/$USER/.steam/ubuntu12_32/' folder and launch the Steam Updater. That will delete the corrupted update (but not the download) and reinstall/reconfigure things all over.

Answer (score 25):

1. Run the following command in terminal:

   ```
   mkdir "/home/$USER/.steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime"
   ```
2. Then launch Steam.

Comment: Worked for me. This answer should be accepted!

Comment: Still works on 18.10, I incurred in the issue after removing the flatpak version, maybe someone else can manage to connect the dots

Comment: Worked on Ubuntu 18.04