# Apps fail to launch even when clicked on

Tags: openvpn, kvm-virtualization

Multiple apps fail to launch from Ubuntu 17.10. When I click on some of the apps  they do not launch.

i tried doing

```
sudo apt install unity
unity --reset-icons
```

when i open a application for example steam), this comes up

```
tar: This does not look like a tar archive
xz: (stdin): File format not recognized
tar: Child returned status 1
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
find: ‘/home/jitu/.steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime’: No such file or directory
```

Comment: this might solve your issue https://askubuntu.com/questions/962737/steam-not-opening-tar-this-does-not-look-like-a-tar-archive